# SPRESENSE Wi-Fi Add-onボードでスプレッドシートにデータを送信する方法

Tags: spresense, google-spreadsheet

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

SpresenseのWi-Fi化を試みています。
SpresenseにSPRESENSE用Wi-Fi add-onボードを取り付けて、値をスプレッドシートに送信したいのですが、HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Requestとなり、送れません。

ESPの場合、WiFiClientSecure.hが使えるので、データ送信できたのですが、SpresenseではWiFiClientSecure.hやESP8266WiFi.hが使えません。
リクエストの仕方が間違っているのでしょうか。

SpresenseとWi-Fi add-onボードを使って、スプレッドシートに値を送信する方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。
長文で申し訳ございません。（プログラムの#defineの#が消えてしまい、文字サイズが大きく表示されてしまいました。）

SPRESENSE用Wi-Fi add-onボード：https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/4042/

### ソースコード

```
// サンプルプログラム：SPRESENSE_ESP8266.inoを改良
// https://github.com/tomorrow56/SPRESENSE_ESP8266
// This is a super simple demo program for ESP8266's that can be used by SPRESENSE
// Serial2 @ 115200 baud.

#define SSID "ポケットWi-FiのSSID"      //your wifi ssid here
#define PASS "パスワード"   //your wifi key here

/* サンプルプログラムのコードをコメント化 */
//  wifitest.adafruit.com/testwifi/index.html
//#define HOST "wifitest.adafruit.com"
//#define WEBPAGE "/testwifi/index.html"
//#define PORT  "80"

/* スプレッドシートにアクセスするために書き換え */
#define HOST "script.google.com"
char* WEBPAGE;
#define PORT  "80"

const char* ssGasID = "スプレッドシートのGasID";


/* スプレッドシートに書き込む値 */
float val1 = 0, val2 = 0, val3 = 0, val4 = 0, val5 = 0, val6 = 0, val7 = 0, val8 = 0, val9 = 0, val10 = 0;

/* サンプルプログラムそのまま */
#define LED_PIN LED0

#define REPLYBUFFSIZ 0xFFFF
char replybuffer[REPLYBUFFSIZ];
uint8_t getReply(char *send, uint16_t timeout = 500, boolean echo = true);
uint8_t espreadline(uint16_t timeout = 500, boolean multiline = false);
boolean sendCheckReply(char *send, char *reply, uint16_t timeout = 500);

enum {WIFI_ERROR_NONE = 0, WIFI_ERROR_AT, WIFI_ERROR_RST, WIFI_ERROR_SSIDPWD, WIFI_ERROR_SERVER, WIFI_ERROR_UNKNOWN};

void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);

  //blink LED0 to indicate power up
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    delay(50);
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    delay(100);
  }

  // Serial debug console
  Serial.begin(115200);

  //Open software serial for chatting to ESP
  Serial2.begin(115200);

  Serial.println(F("SPRESENSE ESP8266 Demo"));

  //connect to the wifi
  /* Wi-Fi接続 */
  byte err = setupWiFi();

  if (err) {
    // error, print error code
    Serial.print("setup error:");  Serial.println((int)err);
    debugLoop();
  }

  // success, print IP
  getIP();

  //set TCP server timeout
  //sendCheckReply("AT+CIPSTO=0", "OK");
}


boolean ESP_GETpage(char *host, uint16_t port, char *page) {
  String cmd = "AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"";
  cmd += host;
  cmd += "\",";
  cmd += port;
  cmd.toCharArray(replybuffer, REPLYBUFFSIZ);

  getReply(replybuffer);

  if (strcmp(replybuffer, "OK") != 0) {
    while (true) {
      espreadline(500);  // this is the 'echo' from the data
      Serial.print("<--- "); Serial.println(replybuffer);
      if (strstr(replybuffer, "OK"))
        break;
    }
  }

  delay(500);

  String request = "GET ";
  request += page;
  request += " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ";
  request += host;
  request += "\r\n\r\n";

  cmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  cmd += request.length();
  cmd.toCharArray(replybuffer, REPLYBUFFSIZ);
  sendCheckReply(replybuffer, ">");

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Sending: "); Serial.println(request.length());
  Serial.println(F("*********SENDING*********"));
  Serial.print(request);
  Serial.println(F("*************************"));
  Serial.println("");

  request.toCharArray(replybuffer, REPLYBUFFSIZ);

  Serial2.println(request);

  while (true) {
    espreadline(3000);  // this is the 'echo' from the data
    Serial.print(">"); Serial.println(replybuffer); // probably the 'busy s...'

    // LOOK AT ALL THESE POSSIBLE ARBITRARY RESPONSES!!!
    if (strstr(replybuffer, "wrong syntax"))
      continue;
    else if (strstr(replybuffer, "ERROR"))
      continue;
    else if (strstr(replybuffer, "busy s..."))
      continue;
    else if (strstr(replybuffer, "OK"))
      break;
    //    else break;
  }

  //  if (! strstr(replybuffer, "SEND OK") ) return false;

  if (! strstr(replybuffer, "OK") ) return false;

  espreadline(50);
  Serial.print("3>"); Serial.println(replybuffer);
  if (char *s = strstr(replybuffer, "+IPD,")) {
    uint16_t len = atoi(s + 5);
    Serial.print(len); Serial.println(" bytes total");
  }

  unsigned long i = 0;
  while (1) {
    char c;
    if (Serial2.available()) {
      c = Serial2.read(); //UDR0 = c;
      //      Serial.write(c);
      replybuffer[i] = c;
      i++;
      delay(1);
      if (!Serial2.available()) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  //while (1) {
  //  if (esp.available()) UDR0 = esp.read();
  //}
}


void loop()
{
  /* 送信データを集めてURLを作成 */
  String url_write = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/";
  url_write += ssGasID;

  url_write += "/exec?";
  url_write += "1_cell=";
  url_write += String(val1);
  url_write += "&2_cell=";
  url_write += String(val2);
  url_write += "&3_cell=";
  url_write += String(val3);
  url_write += "&4_cell=";
  url_write += String(val4);
  url_write += "&5_cell=";
  url_write += String(val5);
  url_write += "&6_cell=";
  url_write += String(val6);
  url_write += "&7_cell=";
  url_write += String(val7);
  url_write += "&8_cell=";
  url_write += String(val8);
  url_write += "&9_cell=";
  url_write += String(val9);
  url_write += "&10_cell=";
  url_write += String(val10);

  Serial.print("SS書き込みURL："); Serial.println(url_write);

  WEBPAGE = url_write.c_str();

  Serial.print("WEBPAGE："); Serial.println(WEBPAGE);


  ESP_GETpage(HOST, 80, WEBPAGE);

  delay(100);

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(F("**********REPLY***********"));
  Serial.println(replybuffer);
  Serial.println(F("**************************"));
  Serial.println("");

  sendCheckReply("AT+CIPCLOSE", "OK");
  while (true) {
    espreadline(3000);  // this is the 'echo' from the data
    Serial.print(">"); Serial.println(replybuffer); // probably the 'busy s...'

    if (strstr(replybuffer, "busy s..."))
      continue;
    else break;
  }

  debugLoop();

  delay(1000);

  while (1);

}


boolean getVersion() {

  // Get version?
  getReply("AT+GMR", 100, true);
  while (true) {
    espreadline(50);  // this is the 'echo' from the data
    Serial.print("<--- "); Serial.println(replybuffer);
    if (strstr(replybuffer, "OK"))
      break;
  }
  return true;
}


/* ESP8266のリセット */
boolean espReset() {
  Serial.println ("espReset");

  getReply("AT+RST", 1000, true);
  if (! strstr(replybuffer, "OK")) return false;
  delay(500);

  // turn off echo
  getReply("ATE0", 250, true);

  return true;
}


boolean ESPconnectAP(char *s, char *p) {

  getReply("AT+CWMODE=1", 500, true);
  if (! (strstr(replybuffer, "OK") || strstr(replybuffer, "no change")) )
    return false;

  String connectStr = "AT+CWJAP=\"";
  connectStr += SSID;
  connectStr += "\",\"";
  connectStr += PASS;
  connectStr += "\"";
  connectStr.toCharArray(replybuffer, REPLYBUFFSIZ);
  getReply(replybuffer, 200, true);

  while (true) {
    espreadline(200);  // this is the 'echo' from the data
    if ((String)replybuffer == "") {
      Serial.print(".");
    } else {
      Serial.println("");
      Serial.print("<--- "); Serial.println(replybuffer);
    }
    if (strstr(replybuffer, "OK"))
      break;
  }

  return true;
}


byte setupWiFi() {

  // reset WiFi module
  Serial.println(F("Soft resetting..."));
  if (!espReset())
    return WIFI_ERROR_RST;

  delay(500);

  Serial.println(F("Checking for ESP AT response"));
  if (!sendCheckReply("AT", "OK"))
    return WIFI_ERROR_AT;

  getVersion();

  Serial.print(F("Connecting to ")); Serial.println(SSID);
  if (!ESPconnectAP(SSID, PASS))
    return WIFI_ERROR_SSIDPWD;

  Serial.println(F("Single Client Mode"));

  if (!sendCheckReply("AT+CIPMUX=0", "OK"))
    return WIFI_ERROR_SERVER;

  return WIFI_ERROR_NONE;
}


boolean getIP() {

  getReply("AT+CIFSR", 100, true);
  while (true) {
    espreadline(50);  // this is the 'echo' from the data
    Serial.print("<--- "); Serial.println(replybuffer);
    if (strstr(replybuffer, "OK"))
      break;
  }

  delay(100);

  return true;
}


/************************/
uint8_t espreadline(uint16_t timeout, boolean multiline) {

  uint16_t replyidx = 0;

  while (timeout--) {
    if (replyidx > REPLYBUFFSIZ - 1) break;

    while (Serial2.available()) {
      char c =  Serial2.read();
      if (c == '\r') continue;
      if (c == 0xA) {
        if (replyidx == 0)   // the first 0x0A is ignored
          continue;

        if (!multiline) {
          timeout = 0;         // the second 0x0A is the end of the line
          break;
        }
      }
      replybuffer[replyidx] = c;
      // Serial.print(c, HEX); Serial.print("#"); Serial.println(c);
      replyidx++;
    }

    if (timeout == 0) break;
    delay(1);
  }
  replybuffer[replyidx] = 0;  // null term
  return replyidx;
}


uint8_t getReply(char *send, uint16_t timeout, boolean echo) { 

  // flush input
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    Serial2.read();
    delay(1);
  }

  if (echo) {
    Serial.print("---> "); Serial.println(send);
  }
  Serial2.println(send);

  // eat first reply sentence (echo)
  uint8_t readlen = espreadline(timeout);

  //Serial.print("echo? "); Serial.print(readlen); Serial.print(" vs "); Serial.println(strlen(send));

  if (strncmp(send, replybuffer, readlen) == 0) {
    // its an echo, read another line!
    readlen = espreadline();
  }

  if (echo) {
    Serial.print ("<--- "); Serial.println(replybuffer);
  }
  return readlen;
}


boolean sendCheckReply(char *send, char *reply, uint16_t timeout) {

  getReply(send, timeout, true);

  /*
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<strlen(replybuffer); i++) {
     Serial.print(replybuffer[i], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<strlen(reply); i++) {
     Serial.print(reply[i], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    }
    Serial.println();
  */
  return (strcmp(replybuffer, reply) == 0);
}


void debugLoop() {
  Serial.println("========================");
  //serial loop mode for diag
  while (1) {
    if (Serial.available()) {
      Serial2.write(Serial.read());
      //      delay(1);
    }
    if (Serial2.available()) {
      Serial.write(Serial2.read());
      //      delay(1);
    }
  }
}
```

### 実行結果

```
SPRESENSE ESP8266 Demo
setupWiFi
Soft resetting...
espReset
getReply
---> AT+RST
espreadline
espreadline
<--- OK
getReply
---> ATE0
espreadline
espreadline
<--- OK
Checking for ESP AT response
sendCheckReply
getReply
---> AT
espreadline
<--- OK
getVersion
getReply
---> AT+GMR
espreadline
<--- AT version:1.6.2.0(Apr 13 2018 11:10:59)
espreadline
<--- SDK version:2.2.1(6ab97e9)
espreadline
<--- compile time:Jun  7 2018 19:34:26
espreadline
<--- Bin version(Wroom 02):1.6.2
espreadline
<--- OK
Connecting to ポケットWi-FiのSSID
ESPconnectAP
getReply
---> AT+CWMODE=1
espreadline
<--- OK
getReply
---> AT+CWJAP="ポケットWi-FiのSSID","パスワード"
espreadline
espreadline
<--- 
espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline

<--- WIFI CONNECTED
espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline

<--- WIFI GOT IP
espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline
.espreadline

<--- OK
Single Client Mode
sendCheckReply
getReply
---> AT+CIPMUX=0
espreadline
<--- OK
getIP
getReply
---> AT+CIFSR
espreadline
<--- +CIFSR:STAIP,"192.168.128.105"
espreadline
<--- +CIFSR:STAMAC,"b4:e6:2d:63:30:0c"
espreadline
<--- OK
SS書き込みURL：https://script.google.com/macros/s/スプレッドシートのGasID/exec?1_cell=0.00&2_cell=0.00&3_cell=0.00&4_cell=0.00&5_cell=0.00&6_cell=0.00&7_cell=0.00&8_cell=0.00&9_cell=0.00&10_cell=0.00
WEBPAGE：https://script.google.com/macros/s/スプレッドシートのGasID/exec?1_cell=0.00&2_cell=0.00&3_cell=0.00&4_cell=0.00&5_cell=0.00&6_cell=0.00&7_cell=0.00&8_cell=0.00&9_cell=0.00&10_cell=0.00
getReply
---> AT+CIPSTART="TCP","script.google.com",80
espreadline
espreadline
<--- OK
sendCheckReply
getReply
---> AT+CIPSEND=259
espreadline
espreadline
<--- > 

Sending: 259
*********SENDING*********
GET https://script.google.com/macros/s/スプレッドシートのGasID/exec?1_cell=0.00&2_cell=0.00&3_cell=0.00&4_cell=0.00&5_cell=0.00&6_cell=0.00&7_cell=0.00&8_cell=0.00&9_cell=0.00&10_cell=0.00 HTTP/1.1
Host: script.google.com

*************************

espreadline
>busy s...
espreadline
>Recv 259 bytes
espreadline
>SEND OK
espreadline
3>+IPD,1382:HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
1382 bytes total

**********REPLY***********
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1555
Date: Thu, 26 Mar 2020 07:20:26 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 400 (Bad Request)!!1</ti
**************************

sendCheckReply
getReply
---> AT+CIPCLOSE
espreadline
<--- CLOSED
espreadline
>OK
debugLoop ========================
```

Answer (score 1):

質問にURLが示されている"SPRESENSE用Wi-Fi add-onボード"のページには、『ESP-WROOM-02（技適取得済）を搭載』と書かれていますので、WiFi add-onボードを使う場合はESPの場合と考えて良いのでは？

[SPRESENSE の Wi-Fi アドオンボードを動かしてみた！](https://makers-with-myson.blog.ss-blog.jp/2019-03-17)　のページを見ると、割と簡単に使えるように思えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
サンプルプログラム通りなら、Wi-Fi接続して、Webpageにアクセスできるのですが、スプレッドシートになるとエラー400が返ってきます。
ということは、リクエストの仕方が原因かなと思いました。

Answer (score 0):

SPRESENSE の ESP-WROOM-02 向けのライブラリを次の github で公開していますので、もしよかったら使ってみてください。

https://github.com/YoshinoTaro/ESP8266ATLib-for-Spresense

Comment: ありがとうございます。
スプレッドシートアクセスのライブラリも是非お願いしたいです。

Comment: お使いのサイトは、https:なのでSSLやTLS等のセキュアな通信が必要になるかと思います。400のエラーが出ているのはそのためだと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。フィンガープリントを試してみようと思います。WiFiClientSecure.hが使えたらいいのですが。。。